# SQL Server - how to make my app work on other computer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
static string domain = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).ToString();
internal static string connect = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= "+domain+"BMS_PRO_DB.mdf;" + "Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";
```

The database is inside the app's location. I think my connection is wrong - that's why the app is working fine on my server but not on the other PC (SQL Server is installed on this PC too).

Please help,

I'm getting the error

> SQL Server not found or not accessible

Comment: LocalDB must be installed and there must be an instance named "MSSQLLocalDB" for that connection string to work. So when you say "SQL Server is installed" do you mean LocalDB or do you mean MSSQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error by installing SQL Server express ==> Features ==> LocalDB,
by installing LocalDB function form SQL Server Setup on the other computer.

It also means that my connection string is perfect!